# Uploading Base64 to Firebase returns 413 status code

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

(First question here e.e)

I'm currently trying to upload images to my Firebase Storage using the **Firebase Admin SDK**.
The main difficulty is that the images are in base64.

Here is my function :

```
public uploadPicture (image: string, path: string): Promise<void> {
    const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET)
    const file = bucket.file(path)
    const content = Buffer.from(image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/, ''), 'base64')
    file.save(content).then(() => console.log('done'))
}
```

I've been trying with some of my images, and got different errors depending on this image.
In some case, the Firebase returned me a `Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)` error, and in other Gaxios (probably a dependency of the Firebase SDK) gives me this error : `Error: The maximum object length is 1024 characters, but got a name with 11596 characters`.

Does someone know how to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Based in the error message I think that maybe the parameters are  switched

please use this fixed variable and validate that the image string is the string of your image:

``` const file = bucket.file('testfile')```

please add an example of the path.